# How to make a an onChange function with typescript that works on all input types?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, typescript-typings

I have the following 2 functions:

```
  function getValue(e: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) {
    let { value, type, checked } = e.target;

    if (type === "number") {
      return parseInt(value, 10);
    }
    if (type === "checkbox") {
      return checked;
    }

    return value;
  }

  function handleChange(e: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) {
    const { name } = e.target;

    setInputs({ ...inputs, [name]: getValue(e) });
  }
```

Here are two example situations:

```
<input
  id="ingrName"
  type="text"
  name="name"
  value={inputs.name}
  disabled={addingIngredient}
  onChange={handleChange}
/>

<select
  id="ingrCat"
  name="categoryId"
  value={inputs.categoryId}
  onChange={handleChange}
>
```

**The issue:**
On the onChange of select, typescript gives the following warning: `Type '(e: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => void' is not assignable to type 'ChangeEventHandler<HTMLSelectElement>'.`

When I add `HTMLInputElement | HTMLSelectElement` to the ts functions, I get the next warning on `{checked}`

```
Property 'checked' does not exist on type 'EventTarget & (HTMLInputElement | HTMLSelectElement)'.
```

Everytime when I try to fix a typescript issue, the next one pops up... I really want to use just one function for all my input elements, but i don't know how to type this function.

Answer (score 0):

change paramater types of both functions as

```
ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement & HTMLSelectElement>
```